# CoreLocation is null and app crashes on launch

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

This is crash log that i get from `Crashlytics`

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0                          0x10015e794 specialized AppDelegate.updateloc(String, long : String) -> () (AppDelegate.swift:350)
1                          0x10015e900 specialized AppDelegate.locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations : [CLLocation]) -> () (AppDelegate.swift:281)
2                          0x10015c058 @objc AppDelegate.locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations : [CLLocation]) -> () (AppDelegate.swift)
3  CoreLocation                   0x18961c8b8 (null) + 21836
4  CoreLocation                   0x189618aac (null) + 5952
5  CoreLocation                   0x189612e48 (null) + 880
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18288900c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
7  CoreFoundation                 0x182888944 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 308
8  CoreFoundation                 0x182886d8c __CFRunLoopRun + 1960
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1827b0d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
10 GraphicsServices               0x184098088 GSEventRunModal + 180
11 UIKit                          0x187a85f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
12                         0x10015c5a0 main (AppDelegate.swift:25)
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x18234e8b8 (Missing)
```

I use `CLLocationmanage`r in `AppDelegate` in order to get user's location when app wakes for location updates.

```
  import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Quickblox
import Fabric
import Crashlytics
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


            if var options = launchOptions {

                if var _: NSNumber = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] as? NSNumber {

                    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

                }
            }

        initLocationManager()


        return true
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

            if  let lat = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude,
                let long = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude {

                 //sends to server to update
                updateloc(String(lat), long: String(long))
            }

        }


    func initLocationManager() {
            if (nil == locationManager) {
                locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            }
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            }

            let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
            if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways ||  status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }

        }
```

Can please help me out some one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `initLocationManager()` before you can use it in `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`.
Try

```
if var options = launchOptions {
    if options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil {
        initLocationManager()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: You may also want to improve your `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` check as I did in the post.

Answer (score 0):

for basic `CLLocationManager` Integration you can check with following `code`. From your `code` i found you are not asking `permission` so you are getting `nil` value.

Try with below `code` may be it will help for you.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        self.initLocationManager()

        /*
        if var options = launchOptions {

            if var _: NSNumber = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] as? NSNumber {
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }
        */

        return true
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if  let lat = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude,
            let long = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude {

                //sends to server to update
//                updateloc(String(lat), long: String(long))
        }

    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }


    func initLocationManager() {

        if (nil == locationManager) {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        }
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        }

        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {

            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        }else if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways ||  status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }
```